# Pure-FTPd: randomly fails with restricted iptables INPUT

Tags: iptables, pureftpd

I've installed Pure-FTPd on a Debian 10 machine that runs `iptables` with de default `DROP` policy for the `INPUT` chain. The `OUTPUT` chain is set to `ACCEPT`.

Problem: if **I try to connect an FTP client it only works sometimes**. It seems to randomly be able to list folders or fail. Usually retrying a new connection will work.

My **Pure-FTPd is configured with these ports**:

```
$ cat /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind
85.xxx.xxx.xxx,57419

$ cat /etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf | grep Port
# Port range for passive connections - keep it as broad as possible.
PassivePortRange             30000 50000
```

To open the ports on the firewall I used:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 57419 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 30000:50000 -j ACCEPT
```

Logs on the server:

```
pure-ftpd]: (?@176.x.x.x) [INFO] New connection from 176.x.x.x
pure-ftpd]: (?@176.x.x.x) [INFO] TLS: Enabled TLSv1.2 with ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 256 secret bits cipher
pure-ftpd]: (?@176.x.x.x) [INFO] testuser is now logged in
// no more output until the client retries a new connection
```

Now the FTP client will say it's listing for a while and then:
[image]

Now, **If I set the iptables `INPUT` chain to `ACCEPT` everything works fine**, so it seems there's some port still blocked that Pure-FTPd randomly tries to use, how can I debug this / fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track this to a configuration issue.

Apparently setting ports at `/etc/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.conf` isn't enough. With further analysis with `ss -nap | grep pure` I found out that pure was trying to use ports outside the ranges allowed in the firewall.

To fix this I just to create a file at `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange` and also set the port range there.